# Using regular expression in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

Is there any library file for using regular expression in visual basic?
I could not find anything please help.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

at the top of your class

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Basic .NET (ie. Visual Studio.NET 2002 and later): .NET includes a regex engine accessed via types in the [`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx) namespace with usage documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).

In earlier (COM based) versions of Visual Basic (up to and including V6) there is a, somewhat more limited, regex engine in the Windows scripting runtime also documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Comment: if i want to do this in C then what should i do . please help

Comment: @insanity: In Standard C: look at third party regex libraries (there are a few). In C + COM you can use the scripting engine, but COM is hard work in C (C++ and something like ATL makes it enormously easier). Of course standard C++ includes regex as part of the library (vS2012 and VS2013 include a pre-standard version).

Comment: can u help me find regex libraries for c in windows. I did searched it in google but cant find it. please help me

Comment: @insanity The key to search is to know that there is a port of Perl 5's regex into a C library: [http://www.pcre.org/](http://www.pcre.org/).